# Optgroup is a bit moved to right in Chrome but shows fine in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I created select box with optgroup and during developing it, I see that in Chrome, optgroup is moved to right with 1px but shows good in Firefox.

There is my code

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-6" id="test">
  <select aria-invalid="false" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" size="6">
     <option value="120">Option 1</option>
     <option value="122">Option 2</option>
     <optgroup label="Optgroup 1">
        <option value="201">Option 1</option>
        <option value="202">Option 2</option>
     </optgroup>
     <optgroup label="Optgroup 2">
        <option value="328">Option 1</option>
        <option value="329">Option 2</option>
        <option value="330">Option 3</option>
     </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#test select {
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
}

#test select option,
#test select optgroup {
  padding: 7px;
}

#test select optgroup > option {
  margin: 0 -7px;
}
```

and JSFiddle: **https://jsfiddle.net/5uaz59qz/**

So, how to fix it in Chrome ?

What will you see in Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

And Firefox (I don't know why children of optgroup are not moved like in Chrome):

[image: Firefox]

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the `:before` pseudo class.

```
option:before{
  display: none;
}
```

```css
#test select {
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
}

#test select option,
#test select optgroup {
  padding: 7px;
}

#test select optgroup > option {
  margin: 0 -7px;
}
option:before{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6" id="test">
  <select aria-invalid="false" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" size="6">
 <option value="120">Option 1</option>
 <option value="122">Option 2</option>
 <optgroup label="Optgroup 1">
    <option value="201">Option 1</option>
    <option value="202">Option 2</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Optgroup 2">
    <option value="328">Option 1</option>
    <option value="329">Option 2</option>
    <option value="330">Option 3</option>
 </optgroup>
  </select>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/5uaz59qz/1/

Comment: see my updated question, I added pictures to understand